# How to create curved bottom navigation like flutter in python kivymd

Tags: flutter, kivymd

I am trying to implement a curved bottom navigation bar in kivymd which will animate like flutter curved bottom navigation bar when any of its item will be clicked. How can I implement that.
Please, give me a suggestion

Answer (score -1):

The only way I could think of is using a bottom app bar where the circles overlap the bottom bar. Then just have the circles be the same color as the background.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).